# Math behind obtaining a charaters Ascii code

Tags: javascript

So, basically I am doing some JS exercises and I understand this code, just cant figure out whats the math behind obtaining characters Ascii code in String.fromCharCode function?
why do we decrement by 18?

Have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

```
function LetterChanges(str) {

str = str.trim().toLowerCase();
var len = str.length;
var newStr = '';

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
if (/[a-ce-gi-mo-su-y]/.test(str[i])) {
    newStr += String.fromCharCode(((str[i].charCodeAt(0) - 18) % 26) + 
97)    
}
else if (/[zdhnt]/.test(str[i])) {
    newStr += String.fromCharCode(((str[i].charCodeAt(0) - 18) % 26) + 
65);
}
else {
 newStr += str[i]; 
}
}
return newStr; 

}


LetterChanges(readline());
```

Comment: I can't exactly know what's going on unless you post what the code is supposed to be doing... Is this one of the problems from CoderByte or sth

Comment: Show us what you have done to try to understand the code and edit your question so that it is specific to what you are asking. Homework questions are okay for Stack Overflow but you will need to do some work. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About ASCII**

Well, as you know, computers don't store characters as 'a', 'b', 'z' or '.', they only accept binary bits (0 or 1). These binary bits can be used to form integers and numbers, but not strings and characters.

So how does the computer store characters? That's where [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (American Standard Code for Information Interchange) comes in.

So the idea is that each character needs to be **stored as a number**, and ASCII code is then the standardization for what number corresponds to what character and vice versa.

**So to answer your first question:** `String.fromCharCode(x)` is just returning you the  character in the standardized ASCII table corresponding to the number `x`. For eg, `String.fromCharCode(65)` will return you '`A`' because the ASCII code for '`A`' is standardized by the standard as 65.

**Why -18**

It's a clever (but confusing) hack to force all the lowercase letters to the character following it.

Because `str` has been made to be lowercase by the line `str = str.trim().toLowerCase();`, str[i] will now only contain values from 97 ('a') to 97+25 = 122 ('z').
Now `18 = 122 (mod 26)` or `122%26`.

This is necessary to accommodate for the fact that 'z' needs to go to 'a', and since we only have 26 characters from 'a' to 'z' that we need to "wrap around" (modulus/`%`)

**Note that:**

```
(97('a')-18)%26 = 1
(98('b')-18)%26 = 2
...
(122('z')-18)%26 = 0
```

So when you add 97 ('a') to each of the numbers you get a function mapping of 'a'->'b', 'b'->'c', ... , 'z'->'a'

Answer (score 1):

Fact: charCode for 'a' is 97,  and (97 - 18) % 26 == 1

Take 'b' for example, `(98 - 18) % 26 == 2`, so after change, its charCode equals `97 + 2 == 99`, becomes 'c'. This rule applies to all 'a-z'.

Now you should see the pattern.

Quiz: what if you want to change uppercase letters, what would you pick as the "magic number" for this case?